# How to create a mapValues recursively function in scala

Tags: scala

i've started to work with scala lately, an not so good at it...
i'm trying to write a function a little like map values that will map values recursively, what i mean by that ,you can  see in the following example.

i've tried to add this function to Map object, but it keeps saying that 
"recursive method must have a return type" although i think i've understand the problem i can't seem to find a proper solution.

thanks for the help!

```
val x = Map(1 -> 1,2 -> Map(3 -> 3))


implicit class mapOps (map:Map){

  def mapRec[T](obj:T):String = obj match{
    case x: Int => x.toString
    case x:Map => x.mapRec(_)
  }
}
```

this is the result i would like to get:

```
Map(1 -> "1", 2 -> Map(3 -> "3"))
```

**SOLUTION**

thnks to **curious** i've managed to find a solution for my problem

```
implicit class mapOps[A](map:Map[A,Any]) {
  def mapRec(): Map[A, Any] = {
    map.mapValues {
      case x: Int => x.toString
      case x: Map[A, Any] => x.mapRec()
    }
  }
}
```

it's a little bit more generic.

Comment: It says you need a return type so give `mapRec` a return type

Comment: Also you haven't started your pattern matching correctly

Comment: It means you need something along the lines of `def mapRec[T](obj: T): String = obj match {  ... }`. Recursive methods in Scala need an explicit return type defined.

Comment: but i can't give it a return type, cause it sometimes return's a string and sometimes just a Map, so witch of the two??

Comment: I think you misunderstand how recursion works. From your code, it will always return a string or fail (as you have no default case). Unless of course you want a different behaviour for `mapRec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of your `x` is `Map[Int, Any]` and you need to give a return type to the tail-recursive function and map the values using `mapValues` on given input map i.e `x` and .

```
  @tailrec
    def map(m: Map[Int, Any]): Map[Int, Any] = {
      m.mapValues {
        case x: Int => x.toString
        case x: Map[Int, Any] =>map(x)  
    }
 }

scala> val x = Map(1 -> 1,2 -> Map(3 -> 3))
x: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Any] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> Map(3 -> 3))

scala> map(x)
res1: Map[Int,Any] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> Map(3 -> 3))
```